# Clans fab menu floating doesn't work with LinearLayout and Coordinatorlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

I am Using Snack bar and FAB in my application ,Whenever Snackbar is Showing Floating Action button not Going up.
i chanched to coordinatlayout anything change please help me i need it and I tried some solution here ana nothing change .

LinearLayout :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDkyX.png)

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ClientMapAct">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorText"
        app:title="TechSi"
        android:background="@color/colorTaxi">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ClientMapAct">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10sp">
        <fragment android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"/>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="50"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#ffc80a"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#c79400"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_fab_hide_animation="@anim/fab_hide_to_bottom"
        fab:menu_fab_show_animation="@anim/fab_show_from_bottom"
        fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
        fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444444"
        fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
        fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
        fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
        fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingBottom="4dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingLeft="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingRight="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingTop="4dp"
        fab:menu_labels_position="left"
        fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
        fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
        fab:menu_labels_textColor="#FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_textSize="14sp"
        fab:menu_openDirection="up"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
        fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
        fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
        fab:menu_shadowYOffset="3dp"
        fab:menu_showShadow="true">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_info_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_identity"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#ffc80a"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#c79400"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            fab:fab_label="Information"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_logout_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logout"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#ffc80a"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#c79400"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            fab:fab_label="Logout"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logout"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#ffc80a"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#c79400"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            fab:fab_label="test"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/request"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_btn"
        android:text="Call TechSi" />

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Coordinatorlayout  :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z8At.png)

XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ClientMapAct">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorText"
        app:title="TechSi"
        android:background="@color/colorTaxi">
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ClientMapAct">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10sp">

        <fragment android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="50"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#ffc80a"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#c79400"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_fab_hide_animation="@anim/fab_hide_to_bottom"
        fab:menu_fab_show_animation="@anim/fab_show_from_bottom"
        fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
        fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444444"
        fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
        fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
        fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
        fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingBottom="4dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingLeft="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingRight="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingTop="4dp"
        fab:menu_labels_position="left"
        fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
        fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
        fab:menu_labels_textColor="#FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_textSize="14sp"
        fab:menu_openDirection="up"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
        fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
        fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
        fab:menu_shadowYOffset="3dp"
        fab:menu_showShadow="true">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_info_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_identity"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#ffc80a"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#c79400"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            fab:fab_label="Information"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_logout_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logout"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#ffc80a"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#c79400"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            fab:fab_label="Logout"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logout"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#ffc80a"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#c79400"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            fab:fab_label="test"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/request"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_btn"
        android:text="Call TechSi" />

</FrameLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Dependencies :

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-java:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation "com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02"
```

I need like that please : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLgGo.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ClientMapAct">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorText"
        app:title="TechSi"
        android:background="@color/colorTaxi">
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ClientMapAct">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10sp">

        <fragment android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="50"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#ffc80a"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#c79400"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_fab_hide_animation="@anim/fab_hide_to_bottom"
        fab:menu_fab_show_animation="@anim/fab_show_from_bottom"
        fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
        fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444444"
        fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
        fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
        fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
        fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingBottom="4dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingLeft="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingRight="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingTop="4dp"
        fab:menu_labels_position="left"
        fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
        fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
        fab:menu_labels_textColor="#FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_textSize="14sp"
        fab:menu_openDirection="up"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
        fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
        fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
        fab:menu_shadowYOffset="3dp"
        fab:menu_showShadow="true">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_info_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_identity"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#ffc80a"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#c79400"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            fab:fab_label="Information"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_logout_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logout"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#ffc80a"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#c79400"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            fab:fab_label="Logout"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logout"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#ffc80a"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#c79400"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            fab:fab_label="test"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/request"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_btn"
        android:text="Call TechSi" />

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Use RelativeLayout** 
And try to avoid androidX build use Android App Compat.